# Mongoose cannot do deep populate

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I've:

1. `User` model (from `UserSchema`)
2. `Specialty` model (from `SpecialtySchema`)
3. `Session` model (from `SessionSchema`)

User has reference field `specialities` :

```
specialities: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Specialty' }]
```

Session has reference field `provider` :

```
provider: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Session' }
```

I want to get list of sessions with populated `provider` (User) and deep populated `specialities` over `provider`.

I'm doing following:

```
Session
  .find()
  .populate({
    path: 'provider',
    model: 'User',
    populate: {
      path: 'specialities',
      model: 'Specialty',
    }
  })
```

However the results always return an array of IDS (when I try to access them by `provider.specialities` instead of the populated version.

Is specialities a keyword?

I don't know why it's like not populating at all.

Comment: Please paste your schemas

Comment: Where is deep population? Simply `mongoose.model('User').findById(id here).populate('specialities')...` and so on...

Comment: i thought for mongoose ver 4 on wards you could deep populate like this ?
 .populate({
    path: 'provider',
    model: 'User',
    populate: {
      path: 'specialities',
      model: 'Specialty',
    }
  })

Comment: @num8er that works, for normal population, but when i try to deep populate a Session model's provider's specialities it does not work

Comment: @DarkArtistry can You add Your code where You `try to deep populate a Session model's provider's specialities` ?

Comment: @num8er yeah im trying to do that, to deep populate a Session model's provider's specialities. The deep population codes are right at the top

Comment: @DarkArtistry You mean You keep an object in `req.session.user` and want to populate specialities? You have to show how You get that session model instance

Comment: i did Session.find()  .populate({
    path: 'provider',
    model: 'User',
    populate: {
      path: 'specialities',
      model: 'Specialty',
    }
  })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick solution is to use [mongoose-deep-populate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-deep-populate)

In every schema attach it as plugin:

```
const deepPopulate = require('mongoose-deep-populate')(mongoose);
SessionSchema.plugin(deepPopulate, {
  whitelist: ['provider', 'provider.specialities']
});
```

and then use it like this:

```
const Session = mongoose.model('Session');
cons user = await Session.findById(id here)
                         .deepPopulate(['provider', 'provider.specialities']);
```

Due to possible performance issues I don't recommend to do deep populate.

Better to try to re-think Your data.

Also I cannot imagine use case for it.

Maybe You just want to show user list with specialities?

What about just to do 2 api calls from frontend:

```
1st for taking sessions and taking provider ids (ex.: GET /sessions), 

2nd for taking users with populated specialities (ex.: GET /users?ids=first-id,second-id...)
```

or:

```
let sessions = await Session.find();
let providerIds = sessions.map(session => session.provider);
let users = await User.find({_id: providerIds}).populate('specialities');

sessions = sessions.map(session => {
  session.provider = users.find(user => user._id == session.provider);
  return session;
});
```

Comment: i will use the solution with out requiring the extra library, thank you